# Downloading multiple SRA files as FASTQ files using SRA Toolkit

Tags: fastq, sratoolkit, sra, fastq-dump

I was able to download all of the SRA files for a specific bioproject using the command:

```
prefetch -O output_directory --option-file SRR_Acc_List.txt
```

I then tried the following command to download those SRA files into FASTQ files:

```
find -name \*.sra -exec bsub fastq-dump --split-3 --gzip {} \;
```

It gave the error:

```
find: illegal option -- n
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
```

I then tried to add the path:

```
find /Users/lucykelly/Desktop/Assel_paper/output_directory -name '*.sra' -exec bsub fastq-dump --split-3 --gzip {} \;
```

It gave the error:

```
find: bsub: No such file or directory
```

I then tried

```
find . -name '*.sra' -exec fasterq-dump --gzip {} \;
```

and it gave the error:

```
find: fasterq-dump: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I agree with @ATPoint. At first I thought it was bsub within the Slurm cluster. If you use `which fasterq-dump` it should throw a blank. The `bsub` error is weird because you should be on the cluster right? Anyway once diagnosed its easy to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a classical problem where the folder containing the binary of the tool is not in PATH, see for example https://askubuntu.com/questions/109381/how-to-add-path-of-a-program-to-path-environment-variable or many other threads towards PATH in the SE network.

Comment: Thank you so much @ATpoint